# importing imdb data by imdbpy still is not finished after 20 hours

Tags: python, import, imdb, imdbpy

I am trying to import imdb's data using IMDbPY which I downloaded from this link:

https://bitbucket.org/alberanid/imdbpy

The problem is that I ran imdbpy2sql yesterday and still after 21 hours it is not finished!
and also it has a lot of warnings like this:

```
 * FLUSHING SQLData...
WARNING: unknown exception caught committing the data
WARNING: to the database; report this as a bug, since
WARNING: many data (10499999 items) were lost: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mona/Downloads/CSV/cast_info.csv'
SCANNING actor: Rosenthal, Laurence Todd
SCANNING actor: Ross, Jonathan (I)
WARNING: unknown exception caught committing the data
WARNING: to the database; report this as a bug, since
WARNING: many data (2746715 items) were lost: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mona/Downloads/CSV/title.csv'
WARNING: unknown exception caught committing the data
WARNING: to the database; report this as a bug, since
WARNING: many data (1442910 items) were lost: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mona/Downloads/CSV/name.csv'
 * FLUSHING SQLData...
WARNING: unknown exception caught committing the data
WARNING: to the database; report this as a bug, since
WARNING: many data (10519999 items) were lost: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mona/Downloads/CSV/cast_info.csv'
SCANNING actor: Rossi, Riccardo (I)
SCANNING actor: Rotmund, Ernst
```

Is it normal?

I am working on a server (Ubuntu version 13.10, core i7, 64 bit with 8 G Ram) and I installed IMDbPY with its dependencies. The database is mysql.

Any kind of information about this problem is highly appreciated

Many thanks
Mona

Comment: Are you sure your SQL base is working ? It seems to me that IMDBPy is unable to write to the database.